# Function constant on fibers of Bernoulli shift must be constant

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a probability space and $(\Omega,\beta)$ be the corresponding Bernoulli space, that is, $\Omega = X^\mathbb N$ and $\beta = \mu^\mathbb N$. Let $T:\Omega \to \Omega$ be the (one-sided) shift map.

I'm looking for a reference for the following result, which I believe is true:

If  a measurable function $\varphi$ is constant (almost everywhere) on the fibers of $T^{n}$ for every $n\geq 1$ then $\varphi$ must be constant almost everywhere. This sounds like a well-known result, but I couldn't find it in any ergodic theory book I know.

*Remark*: I don't assume $X$ to be finite. If it helps, one might suppose that $\varphi$ is in $L^1$ or $L^\infty$.

Comment: I don't think this is true, since I think everything is constant almost everywhere on the fibers of $T^n$ for every $n \ge 1$. If I'm not mistaken, the fibers of $T^n$ are the sets of the form $E_{x_{n+1},x_{n+2},\dots} := \{(y_i)_{i=1}^\infty : y_i = x_i \text{ for all } i \ge n+1\}$. Each of these sets has measure $0$, so any function is constant almost everywhere on each of these sets.

Comment: do you agree? ${}$

Comment: By constant on the fiber I mean that the value of the function is the same in any two given points $\omega$ and $\omega'$ such that $T \omega = T \omega'$. The fact that the fibers have measure zero doesn't play a role here. For instance, for a map $f:X \to Y$, any function of the form $\varphi = \psi \circ f$ is constant on the fibers of $f$, regardless whether they have measure zero or not.

Comment: what?? I asked what "constant almost everywhere on the fibers of $T^n$ meant", not what "constant on the fibers of $T^n$" meant.

Comment: ah, ok. I see you point. In the case of the Bernoulli shift the each fiber of $T$ is naturally isomorphic to $X$ which is equipped with the measure $\mu$. Almost everywhere on a fiber means almost everywhere w.r.t. $\mu$